# Using NewForm on a page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wiki-pages, newform

I've tried a few things and tried searching around, but the information I have found doesn't really tell me how to achieve this.

I want to include the add new item form from a list in a page. There will be a few images on the page and some plain text paragraphs. Then, I want just the entry form to appear underneath so users don't need to follow a link to the list etc.

I found one solution that mentioned using SPD, but this didn't really explain how they had done this, just stating this was the only thing that worked for them.

If anyone could explain how to do this or can find a how to guide, I would appreciate it greatly.

**UPDATE**:
I found this answer on a similar question but when I access the page it's blank.

"So it turns out that SharePoint Designer is the only way to accomplish this. You have to go into the page in Designer, edit the page, and select the Insert tab from the ribbon -> New Item Form -> select "CUSTOM LIST FORM..." (not one of the pre-populated lists or you will get the barebones default content type!) -> Choose the list for the form you want to show and the content type, click OK -> Save the page in SP Designer and it will now show on the page embedded as a form. Success!"

Comment: can you please let us know which SharePoint version are you working with?

Comment: Sorry I'm using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by going into it the opposite way.

rather than attempting to add the NewForm into the page I have added the page content (images and paragraphs) to the form.

I did this by creating a new NewForm and editing within designer. Now rather than linking to a page I have a hyperlink directly to the customized NewForm.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a form in a page this way:

1. Add a Page Viewer Web Part to the page.
2. Edit the web part's properties and give it the URL to the form page (display the New form and copy the URL), but add "&IsDlg=1" to the end of the URL. This will show just the form, but not the rest of the page content like ribbons and quick launch.
3. After the user completes the form, it will by default redirect to the list page. To change this, edit the &source= part of the form's URL to use the URL of the "thank you" or other page to redirect to. This could be back to the page with the Page View Web Part. (see: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-redirecting-to-page-after.html)

Comment: I tried this but every time I did the only area shown in the Page Viewer Web Part would be the Ribbon. Not sure why but even adding &IsDlg=1 didn't make a difference to this.

2. The web part would remove itself after the page had been refreshed.